# How to Pass Images through Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

My intention is to get the pictures from gallery and pass it through intent. I've already done the first part. And maybe this question has been already asked once here, but I'm very new and still not sure how the process of passing images through intent works. I've tried half way and got stuck. Below is my code.

```
fun ShowImage(){
        val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 
IMAGE_PICK_CODE && data != null){
            image_view.setImageURI(data.data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont pass the image itself, save the image then pass the path in the intent

Comment: Either save the image and pass the location through intent, or you can convert the image to a Base64 string and pass that through (not recommended)

Comment: any update for this?

Comment: It works as I thought how I would. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FirstActivity**

```
intent.putExtra("uri", data?.data.toString());
```

**SecondActivity**

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("uri"));
```